# Getting 'ValueError: Cant convert string to float' error in python

Tags: python, pandas

i have this error doing the Titanic Dataset from Kaggle

```
scoring = "accuracy"
score = cross_val_score(clf, train_data_2, target, cv=k_fold, n_jobs=1, scoring=scoring)
print(score)

C:\Users\onlyj\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'
```

So found this is the error on my code

```
for dataset in train_test_data:
    dataset["Embarked"] = dataset["Embarked"].fillna("S")
```

Tried to change this

```
for dataset in train_test_data:
    dataset["Embarked"] = dataset["Embarked"].fillna(float("S"))
```

But gives me this

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'S'
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. Why do you want to convert the letter `S` to a `float`? And what would that look like as a outcome?

Comment: What is the numerical value of S?  Python can't convert a letter into a number...

Comment: What is the data type of the "Emabarked" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Embarked' column is categorical data. You should convert it to dummy variables.

```
embark = pd.get_dummies(dataset['Embarked'], drop_first=True)
dataset = dataset.drop('Embarked')
dataset = pd.concat([dataset, embark], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code, here:

```
for dataset in train_test_data:
    dataset["Embarked"] = dataset["Embarked"].fillna("S")
```

You cannot convert a string (the letter S in this case) to a float. Use something like:

```
for dataset in train_test_data:
    dataset["Embarked"] = dataset["Embarked"].fillna(0.00)
```

If you want that field to be a float.

Comment: You´re right i donnt know what i was really doing, thank you that solved my problem !